# What is the correct form? Is it "in den Zeiten" or "in der Zeiten"?

Tags: grammatical-case

Why "in den Zeiten", like in the translation of the title "Die Liebe in den Zeiten der Cholera
"? Why not "in der Zeiten"?

Comment: What case do you think "der Zeiten" is?

Comment: @phipsgabler: Dativ?

Comment: I see, that explains why you're asking... it's genitive (plural).

Comment: @phipsgabler Why do you ask the OP about his opinion on the option that (you know) is wrong instead of the right one? This is confusing.

Comment: With a little stretch, we could construct some poetry where *der* would be grammatical: "In der Zeiten stetem Lauf / Tritt Liebe und auch Chol'ra auf" (ouch, sorry).

Comment: @cp Not their opinion. Their understanding. Since they explicitely wondered why it is not _der Zeiten_, and I wanted to understand the reasoning behind that thought. (It could as well have been the misunderstanding that _in_ takes a genitive, for example.)

Answer (score 8):

*In*, in the nondirectional (temporal) sense of *in den Zeiten* "in the times", takes the dative case.  The datives of *die Zeit* are *der Zeit* (Sg) and *den Zeiten* (Pl).

*Der Zeiten* could be a correct genitive plural form, but that doesn't work in this phrase, unless you have a very poetic construction like *in der Zeiten Lauf* "in the run of times", where the phrase *der Zeiten* is just a possesive apposition in a funny embedded place.

*In* can also be used in a directional sense, like *in die Schule* "to school".  In that case, it takes the accusative case: *in die neuen Zeiten* "towards the new times".

Comment: I am confused. In the comment above you said "genitive" and here you say "dative".

Comment: I always said _der Zeiten_ is genitive. It's just not correct with _in_, which is why I explained the dative as well.

Comment: However, it should be "in Zeiten" without any article.

Comment: @mic https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Liebe_in_den_Zeiten_der_Cholera

Comment: Why locative? Why not temporal?

Comment: Temporal expressions are almost always construed in terms of locative metaphors. But your right in that it might not convey the meaning in intended.

Comment: @phipsgabler oh, I misunderstood what you were referring to. I thought `der Zeiten` was referring to its use in `in der Zeiten`. So the answer then is "we _need_ Dative, which `den Zeiten` is, and can't use `der Zeiten`, because it is Genitive"

Comment: Yes, exactly! Sorry if that was unclear, I'll try to reword it.